# jquery-ui dialogs lose auto size

Tags: jquery

In IE is fine.
But in FF/Chrome, create a modal dialog, with width/height as auto, eg.

```
$('<div id="testPopup"></div>').dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: data.title,
        width: "auto",
        height: "auto",
```

Then if the dialog dynamically adds new buttons, the dialog is expands/resizes fine. However, if you drag/move the dialog, then the width/height attributes are replaced with exact numeric values. Then adding new buttons dynamically will be squashed or even can't be shown.

I've tested this in both jquery-ui 1.11.4 and 1.12.1

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add attributes

draggable: true
dragStop: function(event, ui) {...}

need to test for not being isieversion()
then temporarily store the width ($(this).dialog("option", "width")) and then setting it again.